# How to show date in f.collection_select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, drop-down-menu, haml

I want to show the date of holidays in a dropdown menu within the

_scheduled_holiday_fields.html.haml

```
%td= f.collection_select :holiday_id, SystemHoliday.all + TenantHoliday.where(tenant: @tenant),:id, :name, include_blank: "-- Select Holiday --", hide_label: true
```

Currently in the dropdown menu it shows as:

```
Holiday      
Christmas
```

In the dropdown menu I want to show as:

```
Holiday
Christmas (Dec 25)
```

I have a separate page for a person to enter the holidays they observe as well as the date for the holiday.

my form view:

```
= bootstrap_nested_form_for(@schedule,bsf_opts) do |f|
  .section
    .section_header Scheduled Holidays
    .panel.panel-primary
      .panel-body Select the holidays observed by your company as well as the office mode for each holiday.
      %table.data#scheduled_holidays_table
        %thead
          %tr
            %th
            %th Holiday
        %tbody
          = f.fields_for :scheduled_holidays, wrapper: false
      .panel-footer
        .center= f.link_to_add "Add Holiday", :scheduled_holidays, class: :button, data: {target: "#scheduled_holidays_table"}
```

_scheduled_holiday_fields.html.haml:

```
%tr.fields
  %td= f.collection_select :holiday_id, SystemHoliday.all + TenantHoliday.where(tenant: @tenant),:id, :name, include_blank: "-- Select Holiday --", hide_label: true
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". Reduce your code to the absolute bare minimum necessary to reproduce the problem. Anything beyond that slows our answering as we sift through what is essential and what is junk, and, often, in the middle of that process people give up and move on to other questions. Often, during that process you'll actually find the solution to your question because you're pruning away non-essential parts.

Comment: @theTinMan Thank you! I have edited my question and cut down on significant code that was not needed.

Comment: Which collection_select do you want to show the date?

Comment: @FeifeiXiong in the `_scheduled_holiday_fields.html.haml` `%td= f.collection_select :holiday_id, SystemHoliday.all + TenantHoliday.where(tenant: @tenant),:id, :name, include_blank: "-- Select Holiday --", hide_label: true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to "[`collection_select`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)":

```
# Add attr_accessor and collection_select text_method to Holiday
class Holiday < ActiveRecord::Base

  def name_with_date
    "#{name} (#{to_s})"
  end
end


# Then modify the form input
%td= f.collection_select :holiday_id, SystemHoliday.all + TenantHoliday.where(tenant: @tenant), :id, :name_with_date, include_blank: "-- Select Holiday --", hide_label: true
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work. I am getting an error `undefined local variable or method 'month' for SystemHoliday` I have included my `model for schedule` as well. Could it be because `month` is a class constant variable?

Comment: @dgosh `_holiday_time_range_fields`, how system_holid call it and get the month? like system_holiday.holiday_time_range.month? could you post SystemHoliday model as well?

Comment: I have updated the post with the SystemHoliday model and the TenantHoliday model. It gets the month in the view by `:month, Schedule::MONTHS :last, :first` and it gets called in the `edit.html.haml` in the `SystemHoliday` view

Comment: Hi @dgosh In your project, the schedule has_many holidays through scheduled_holidays, and the schedule has_many weekly_time_ranges, yearly_time_ranges? Which model has the attributes month and day_of_month?

Comment: the model that has the attributes `month` and `day_of_month` is `Schedule.rb` model

Comment: @dgosh Got it, does one holiday will only be and must be associated with one schedule? Because the schedule model has the attributes month and day_of_month. And we will show the date of each holiday.

Comment: any amount of schedules can be made with same holidays or different holidays but those holidays selected within a particular schedule will only be seen in that schedule

Comment: Got it, so the schedule has attributes month and day_of_month. And you want to show date in the dropdown menu when adding new holiday association?

Comment: I am getting an `undefined method 'month' for Schedule` I won't be a able to call it as `@schedule.month` since `month` and `day_of_month` are not in methods but constant variables. Would I have to do something like this `Schedule::Months`? But not sure how I would be able to do that

Comment: I solved the issue. I used your first answer with the method and put it in `Holiday` model but instead of `"#{name} (#{month} #{day_of_month})"` i did ` "#{name} (#{to_s})" I saw the method `to_s` in the `Holiday` model and that what was keeping the day and month. If you change your answer to this I will mark it as correct! Thank you for everything